# MobileFirst - what should i need to do if new version of IBM Apps Center is uploaded

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have a customized IBM Apps Center in the Application Center, if I want to upload a new version (same bundle ID but changing aaps name/apps icon), what should I need to do to the current Apps Center in the phone?

Is Mobile First have the feature to auto update the Apps Center on the next startup after new version is uploaded ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change name and icon by keeping `bundleId` same in the new version of the application. 
Refer [this](http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/appcenter/appcenter-console/#upgrading-a-mobile-application-in-mobilefirst-server-and-the-application-center) documentation on how to upload a new version of application in the IBM Application Center.

If your application is built with MobileFirst SDK, You can disable the old version of the application and mandate users to move to the latest version of the application by giving an upgrade link.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I know I can do that to the apps that uploaded to the application center, but I want to know is the mobile client itself (IBM Apps Center) have the auto update feature if the new mobile client(IBM Apps Center) is uploaded ? FYI, I'm not using the mfpconsole, I'm just using the ApplicationCenter to upload apps and download the apps thru the mobile client.

Comment: Nope, their is no such feature available in Application Center.

Comment: so means that the user have to uninstall and then install new mobile client again ?

Comment: Nope, User can go to app center and update it to latest version.